# Can not take texture view screenshot in android

Tags: android, textureview, takesscreenshot

I have a texture view on which a video is getting played. I need to take screenshot of the frame of playing video. Earlier I was using a method

```
public Bitmap getFrameAsBitmap() {
        Bitmap bmp = textureview.getBitmap();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        textureview.draw(canvas);
        return bmp;
    }
```

It is working fine on most of the devices but on Samsung M series I can not take screenshot. Only black screen is coming.
Then I tried

```
public Bitmap getFrameAsBitmap() {
        View view = textureview;
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        textureview.draw(canvas);
        return bmp;
    }
```

But this method is not returning data on any phone. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Have you tried drawing textureview's bitmap on a new canvas? new paint? Or just return the bitmap directly?

Comment: I am creating a new canvas object. The problem is that a video is getting played on the texture view so instead of the actual frame only a black screen is getting captured. So I used textureview.getbitmap() method is working fine on most phones but does not work on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several things that you can try.

**Return the bitmap directly.**

```java
public Bitmap getFrameAsBitmap() {
    return textureview.getBitmap();
}
```

**Clone the bitmap then return the clone.**

```java
public Bitmap getFrameAsBitmap() {
    Bitmap bmp = textureview.getBitmap();
    Bitmap clone = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    return clone;
}
```

**Draw the bitmap on a new canvas.**

```java
public Bitmap getFrameAsBitmap() {
    Bitmap bmp = textureview.getBitmap();
    //Try using bitmap's width/height first, if it does not work, use view's width/height instead.
    Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBmp);
    //It is not efficient to create a Paint object too often. Better make it as global variable.
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
    return newBmp;
}
```